# 'Assertion failed' error while using node-canvas

Tags: node-canvas

I want to use node-canvas and when I try to render text, I get this Error:

> Assertion failed: (!scaled_font->cache_frozen), function
>   _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy, file cairo-scaled-font.c, line 459. Abort trap: 6

Here some sample code:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
ctx._setFont(Weight, Style, FontSize, 'px', 'Arial')
ctx.fillText("Hello, World!", 50, 50)
```

**.fillText** crashed all the time, with the same error.

Maybe it's a problem with cario. Not sure what's going wrong there.

My set up:

Mac OS 10.13.6, canvas@^2.0.0-alpha.17 and installed the packages via brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg.

I wrote some comment at github here: [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/912)

Answer (score 0):

I find this post on [github](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/837). When i use node **canvas-prebuilt** it works for me. Then there is no problem with text rendering. 
It means installing canvas-prebuild with `npm install canvas-prebuilt` and load the module with `require('canvas-prebuilt')`.